# How to parse elements with Jsoup in given select range?

Tags: java, parsing, jsoup

Hi I am trying to parse whole bunch of html with Jsoup, but cannot achieve the desired goal.
I am parsing it from generated javadoc, which is poor of ids or other helpful elements for parsing. Also another problem is that I have to parse same tags in the same document, so i cannot have strictly defined select. I managed to do it, but still have a problem with method name, which is in the other sibling of the DOM. Here is my html and desired parsing result:http://img62.imageshack.us/img62/9870/08bz.png

I have to 'tie' in some way 'pre' and 'ol' tags (parse the desired html range). Please, help me.

Tryed to do it in such way: `Elements methodName = doc.select("pre:contains(public), dl > dd > ol");`
but this returns me too much methods names.

Comment: I mean, when I execute it, i get too much unwanted info, not just 'public void method_name() and ol list'. I need only this info..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want only the `public void method_name()` and the list items that explain what the method does, but without any additional html tags.

```
Elements methodName = doc.select("pre:contains(public), dl > dd > ol > li");
```

This will select 4 elements in total - the method name and the three list items, but they will still have html tags surrounding them such as `<pre>` and `<li>`. Call the `text()` method on each Element to remove those tags:

```
for (Element e : methodName) {  
    System.out.println(e.text());
}
```

Which outputs:

```
11-08 10:47:19.468: I/System.out(816): public void test()
11-08 10:47:19.468: I/System.out(816): Navigates to app
11-08 10:47:19.468: I/System.out(816): opens main panel
11-08 10:47:19.478: I/System.out(816): starts it
```

---

Due to the lack of any id attributes, I don't think it is possible to select only the relevant tags with one select statement. So instead you could iterate through the `Elements` that you do select and check whether a `<pre>` tag is followed by a `<li>` tag (assuming you use the same `doc.select()` statement I used in my first answer).

Example:

```
Elements methodName = doc.select("pre:contains(public), dl > dd > ol > li");

for (int i = 0; i < methodName.size(); i++) {
    if (methodName.get(i).tagName().equals("pre")) {        // if the <pre> tag
        if (methodName.get(i + 1).tagName().equals("li")) { // is followed by a <li> tag
            System.out.println(methodName.get(i).text());   // print it
        }
    } else System.out.println(methodName.get(i).text());    // else it is a <li> tag so print it
}
```

This will provide the same output as my first example, even if there are two other `<pre>` tags with methodNames that don't have a `<ol>` list following (as you mentioned in your comment).

Note: Depending on how your document is formatted, you might have to watch out for an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` (when I call `i + 1`), but you can just add another check for that.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Yes, I want that result, but there are more these methods in html, which are without method description (<ol> tags). I don't need them in parse result:
<pre>public void method_1()</pre> <pre>public void method_2()</pre> (and my right one with the method description) <pre>public void method_name()</pre><dl><dd><ol>. I need the only one method name which goes above 'dl > dd > ol' element. I don't know how to 'combine them..

Comment: Oh, I think I understand better now. I thought about it for a bit and updated my answer. I can't see any easier way to do it with Jsoup.

Comment: Thank you very much, worked liked a charm, you saved my time:) Syntax is a bit familiar to Selenium2 ;) Sorry, I cannot vote for you answer because I am newbie here..